# MaterialUI ButtonGroup - Active

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I understand that I can do a button group like this, which is great.

However how can I make it so that when say button one is pressed that it looks like it as been selected? As all this does is a click effect?

Basically what I want to do is when a button is clicked it changes an input value to the value of the button. But I would like the button to look like it was selected.

```
    <ButtonGroup disableElevation variant="contained" color="primary">
      <Button>One</Button>
      <Button>Two</Button>
    </ButtonGroup>
```

Answer (score 14):

I'd use state to keep track of the selected `Button` and utilize the `color` prop to assign the color. For arbitrary color, you can use the MUI `ThemeProvider` or `makeStyles`

```js
function App() {

  const [selectedBtn, setSelectedBtn] = React.useState(-1);
 
  return(
    <div>
      <ButtonGroup disableElevation variant="contained" color="primary">
        <Button color={selectedBtn === 1 ? "secondary" : "primary"} onClick={()=>setSelectedBtn(1)}>One</Button>
        <Button color={selectedBtn === 2 ? "secondary" : "primary"} onClick={()=>setSelectedBtn(2)}>Two</Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel">
    const { ButtonGroup, Button } = MaterialUI;
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use Toggle Buttons - https://material-ui.com/components/toggle-button.

Combine that with the ToggleButtonGroup API and you should be good to go - https://material-ui.com/api/toggle-button-group/#togglebuttongroup-api.

Comment: Having a hard time styling the `<ToggleButton>` - I want it to look like a regular button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below:

**SelectedButtonGroup.tsx**:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import ButtonGroup from '@mui/material/ButtonGroup';

const buttons = ['button1', 'button2', 'button3'];

export function SelectedButtonGroup() {

    const [selectedButton, setSelectedButton] = useState<string>(buttons[0]);

    return (
        <ButtonGroup variant="outlined">
            {
                buttons.map(button => (<Button onClick={() => setSelectedButton(button)} variant={selectedButton === button ? 'contained' : 'outlined'}>{button}</Button>))
            }
        </ButtonGroup>
    );
}
```